# Can you go temporarily blind if you experience 18 Hz vibrations?

Tags: clinical-study, vision, blind

[The Wikipedia article on the BAC TSR-2 jet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BAC_TSR-2) states that:

> Shortly after takeoff on XR219's second flight, vibration from a fuel
> pump at the resonant frequency of the human eyeball caused the pilot
> to throttle back one engine to avoid momentary loss of vision.

Wikipedia cites Wood 1986, p. 161. & Gardner 1981, p. 116. to support this, but I was not able to find those books.  Nor was I able to find any study confirming that vibration can lead to temporary loss of vision.

It does make theoretical sense that if you experience vibrations at the resonant frequency (eigenfrequency) of your eyeballs (about 18 Hz), your eyeballs would vibrate a lot and I can imagine how that would make it hard to see.

But what is the medical evidence on this?  Are there any studies that have experimentally confirmed vision loss at 18 Hz?

Comment: FYI "Wood 1986" is the 1986 edition of "Project Cancelled" by D Wood - the 1975 version is on archive.org, but not the more recent one. Gardner 1981 is " British Aircraft Corporation: A History", which is available, though p 112: "Beamont knew that reheat fuel-pump oscillation (it was due to the change of a spring) was causing an airframe vibration, and that this was at a frequency very close to that of the human eyeball. As prototype XR219 climbed away on its second flight, this vibration happened, and ‘Bee,’ to avoid blurred eye-sight, had to throttle back the port engine..."